# How can I upload posts at youtube community tab with API?

Tags: youtube-api

I searched some about it, but I cannot found about it.
How can i upload post at YouTube community tab with YouTube API?
It's not able with v3?

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, I found more information about this in the Google Forums, where they are saying NOT to post developer type questions. I too was looking for an answer here about this.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/QGTZT-M7N_s;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/%22Community$20Tab%22$20and$20API

As of 6/28/18
All API reference and data availability is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Currently content found in the Community tab of a channel is not available to be gathered via the API

---

Development with the API is outside of the scope of this forum.
YouTube's developers have a presence on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api
in which to ask questions about the API.
There are also other resources here: https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/api-resources.html

The community tab is relatively new, so there may not be a lot of published documentation on how to access it with the API.

Hope this helps. I would love to know if this function is going to be added in the future, but not sure where to find that kind of information.