# Does the YouTube Data API support photos & stories uploading?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The native YouTube UI currently supports multiple content types: videos, [community posts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7124175?hl=en) (photos, GIFs, polls)  & [stories](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7568166?hl=en).

The YouTube Data API makes it very clear how to upload videos but I am not able to find information about the other two content types mentioned above, namely community posts & stories.

I did read [this other Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315310/how-can-i-upload-posts-at-youtube-community-tab-with-api), which is essentially about **access existing content** from the Community tab through the API, but I was not able to find any additional information about **posting new content** to the Community tab through the API.

Does anyone know whether the YouTube Data API currently supports uploading community posts & stories to YouTube?